# Including extensions when rolling out a site?

Tags: php

How would one go about setting up using extensions in a live site? My site is coded in PHP and within it, I use the NumberFormatter function - my question is, how would I "bundle" this in with the actual site so that when I upload it to a live server, I don't get an error telling me that it can't find the function?

Comment: `NumberFormatter` is [apparently in 5.3+ via the `intl` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) so if your server is 5.3+ and has the extension enabled in php.ini, you should be fine.  If the server is an older version, you will need to install the extension from PECL.  Many new and interesting PHP libraries are beginning to use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) via packagist.org, and that is very much worth learning about.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Wel now that I've done that, I ran composer and the json inserted symfony/intl into the directory - but how would I call the NumberFormatter with that dependency instead of the regular PHP one (since i still seem to be getting the error)